# Losing math type when using kableExtra styling

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I would like to use kable() and some of the functions in the kableExtra package to display a table that includes different math type (table of laboratory values with different metrics) in a pdf report. However, if I'm using some of the functions in the kableExtra package, the math styling is lost. For example:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

k <- mtcars[c(1:5), c(1:5)]
k[3,3] <- '$\\mu$mm$^3$'

kable(k, escape = TRUE)
```

Works as expected:

[image: math type works]

But if I add in some extra styling, such as add_indent, the math symbols are no longer preserved.

```
kable(k, escape = TRUE) %>%
  add_indent(3)
```

**EDIT:** I've tried both with escape=TRUE and escape=FALSE, and neither produces the desired output.

Results in:

[image: math type does not work]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want `escape = FALSE`.  That says that you have code in your table that you mean to be interpreted as LaTeX code, and you don't want `kable()` to show the input characters.

The main problem is that `kable()` doesn't produce LaTeX output directly unless you ask it to.  You can fix this by using

```
kable(k, escape = FALSE, format = "latex") %>%
  add_indent(3)
```

but then the default formatting changes.  I'd use `kbl()` instead of `kable()`, because it has slightly more sensible defaults.  To get what you had before but with the math handled properly, you could use

```r
kbl(k, escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  add_indent(3) %>%
  kable_styling( latex_options="hold_position")
```

Comment: Thank you! This also worked! And I wasn't aware of the slight differences in kbl() and kable() - appreciate that tip!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use cat and `result: asis`:

````
```{r}
#| results: asis
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

k <- mtcars[c(1:5), c(1:5)]
k[3,3] <- '$\\mu$mm$^3$'

x <- kbl(k, escape = FALSE, format = "html") %>%
  add_indent(3) |> 
  kable_styling()

cat(x)
```
````

Comment: This worked! Thank you for your help. I'd tried this on a handful of reports that I need to generate and so far there haven't been any issues.